# How write one Function that find out all odd number in Common lisp?

Tags: recursion, iteration, common-lisp

Here's my funtion which returns all odd numbers from a list:

```
(defun check-all-oddp (n)
   (cond ((null n) nil)
         ((oddp (first n))
           (cons (first n)
                 (check-all-oddp (rest n))))
         (t (check-all-oddp (rest n)))))
```

that my written using recursion. How can I use `do` to rewrite that without recursion?

Comment: Yeah, that's exercise 11.9 in Touretzky's book. What did you try to solve it and what's your actual problem?

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it is to accumulate a list inside the `do` by prepending only odd numbers to it, and then reversing the list at the end:

```
(defun odds-of (numbers)
  (do ((x numbers (cdr x))
       (odds '() (if (oddp (car x)) (cons (car x) odds) odds)))
      ((null x) 
       (nreverse odds))))
```

The reason we prepend and then reverse, instead of appending, is because prepending is *O(1)* and reversing is *O(n)*, whereas appending is *O(n)* so the repeated appending would lead to quadratic time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't just use higher-order functions like remove-if-not?

```
(defun odds-of (numbers)
    (remove-if-not #'oddp numbers))

(odds-of (loop for x below 10 collect x)) => '(1 3 5 7 9)
```

The community of lisp encourage the use (and reuse) of higher-order functions and about filtering' functions generally is used `remove-if-not` and `remove-if` for that. Check that cool material: [Filter Function](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FilterFunction)